# How to call method of .aspx from .cs file

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I created web page in that i used javascript in .aspx file.

I have a save-button,but in the source code i used javascript for save button, where i declared a function called `OnClientClick="javascript : validateTextTest()"` and in the head of source code i called this function `validateTextTest()`.

Below is the save button in source code:

```
<asp:Button ID="Save"  runat="server" 
   onclick="Save_Click" Text="Save" 
   OnClientClick="javascript : validateTextTest()" Width="63px" />
```

Now i need to call a function `validateTextTest()` in save button of .cs file.Because i have two to three textboxs, if i leave one texbox out of three textbox it should not insert into DB.

So please tell me how to call the function in .cs file.

Answer (score 0):

Insted of doing such things , you can use asp.net validation controls , for your purpose you are going to need a RequieredFieldValidator for each one of your TextBoxes , and you can use them like following code :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtISBN" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RQVISBN" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="txtISBN"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

These controls are greate ! And they do validation on clientSide as you want ;)

Answer (score 0):

validateTextTest is your javascript function which you probably use for some client side validations before submitting to the server. So i dont think you really should use the client side function in your sever side code (.cs file) to validate the input. You should do the same validation inside your server side code also.  Something like this

```
if((!String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text)) && 
               (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text)) && 
                          (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text)))
{
   // Insert to DB    
}
else
{
   //Show validation error message
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to firstly start off by defining the technology stack you are using. Is it ASP.NET or MVC.

I am assuming you are using ASP.NET. Given the way you have already started writing this application. You will need to do a few things to get your approach to work.

```
<form name="myform"> 

<asp:HiddenField runat="server" id="validRequest"/>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 

function validateTextTest()  {       

//validation goes here    

var validRequest = document.getElementById(<%#validRequest.ClientID%>);

//set validation outcome to the validRequest etc

validRequest.value = 'true';
if(validRequest.value == 'true')
   return true;
return false;

    }  </script>  
</form>
```

I forget which one it is but check either your Page_Load etc

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(validRequest.Value == "true")
         //Do whatever you need to
}
```